# Use height of web view for reusable view in collection view

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift3

I have a `UICollectionReusableView` in my `UICollectionView`, in the reusable view, I have put a `UIWebView` and it's the only view in the reusable view. The UIWebView of course varies in size, but I would like to have a header view that fits the whole web view.

But I have no access to the web view in the method `referenceSizeForHeader` in the `UICollectionViewDelegate`, so how can I get the header to be just as long as the content needs to be?